# Urdu language is not listed or installed in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, language-support

I am a new user of Ubuntu, and I installed Ubuntu 15.10 but the Urdu language pack is not installed in my Ubuntu 15.10. I tried many ways to get help by forum, but I have still found no solution. How can I easily add the Urdu language pack in Ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this guide to install a new language:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language-install.html

To type Urdu you may want to install the `ibus-m17n` package. Then log out and log in again. To enable *Urdu (phonetic (m17n))*, follow this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html