# Urdu language not listed in my ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, language-support

I am a new user of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. To my surprise it does not have Urdu Language in language support widow. Kindly help.

The given answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748227/urdu-language-is-not-listed-or-installed-in-my-ubuntu-15-10) is not helping me.

Comment: You might want to include a link to the already given answer, and point out which problems you're facing.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/748227/urdu-language-is-not-listed-or-installed-in-my-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: The question is same, but not helping me. Because it help, when my language support has Urdu language.

Answer (score 6):

*Language Support* includes the languages for which language packs have been created, and language packs are no longer created for languages with a translation coverage below a certain threshold (can't tell exactly what the limit is). Probably that's the explanation why you don't find [Urdu](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+lang/ur).

You may want to install the `fonts-nafees` package to render Urdu web contents.

```
sudo apt install fonts-nafees
```

Possibly you may also want to contact the [Urdu translators team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-ur) and help improve the translation status, so the Urdu language packs can again be included in the distribution. (They were included in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04.)